# Blank screen when requesting Spring Insight at http://localhost:8080/insight

Tags: spring, spring-insight, tcserver

I get a blank screen when opening the page ...host:8080/insight to view the report from Spring Insight on my web app deployed on vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE

It happens if I start the server from within STS 3.5.0.RELEASE or outside and manually from the command line on my Linux box.

Any clue ?

Kind Regards,

Stephane Eybert

Comment: I cannot find the log file when running the server from within STS and I also cannot unpack the war app archive when running the server outside STS. Frustrating day...

Comment: Follow my instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266834/cannot-start-my-spring-application-on-tcserver-from-springtools/23273808#23273808 and deploy your webapp outside STS. You should be able to get a log file while testing like this.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Just seeing your comment, will try now, thanks !

Comment: @AndreiStefan In fact, this other thread lists exactly what I had been doing in the first place. It's too bad we cannot use Insight from a stock Tomcat and have to do with tc-server.

Comment: Any updates when running from outside STS? Do you get a log file?

Comment: The catalina.out log file show nothing when I send a GET request from my browser at http://localhost:8080/insight
In fact the catalina.out log file does not show any line at all on that request.

Comment: The insight.war archive was unpacked fine at start-up time of the server instance.